# Исключение: На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использовался подход Database First.

Имеется часть кода:

```
using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
{
    currentAct = new Act()
    {
        ActNumber = actNumber,
        EntryDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        Employee = currentEmployee
    };

    db.Acts.Add(currentAct); // здесь ловлю исключение!
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

По каким вообще причинам может вылетать это исключение??

Comment: я так понял, `currentEmployee` вы из другого контекста взяли?

Comment: @tym32167, вообще контекст этот же, но другой экземпляр

Comment: @tym32167, вот же... в этом-то и ошибка, получается?

Comment: ну да, у вас в тексте ошибки это написано.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш `currentEmployee` - не простой объект, а объект имеющий ссылку на контекст (точнее, на его Change Tracker, но это почти одно и то же). Отсюда и проблема: такой объект не может одновременно находиться в двух разных контекстах. Отдельно отмечу, что два разных контекста - это два разных объекта, а не два разных класса. Также отмечу, что проблема может быть не только в `currentEmployee`, но и в любом объекте на который `currentEmployee` ссылается.

Способов исправления этой проблемы - целая куча.

Прежде всего, сущности открепляются от контекста при разрушении этого самого контекста:

```
using (var db = new DBContext()) 
{
    currentEmployee = db.Employees.Where(...).Single();
}
// Здесь currentEmployee уже можно использовать в другом контексте
```

Это - основной паттерн использования контекстов, и по возможности именно его следует использовать.

Если же по какой-то причине вы не можете разрушить контекст перед использованием `currentEmployee` - вы можете попытаться не создавать новый контекст, а использовать старый:

```
using (var db = new DBContext()) 
{
    currentEmployee = db.Employees.Where(...).Single();

    var act = new Act { ... };
    db.Acts.Add(act);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Если этот вариант также невозможен - то вы можете открепить `currentEmployee` от контекста перед тем как его куда-то сохранять:

```
currentEmployee = db.Employees.Where(...).Single();
db.Entry(currentEmployee).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

С той же целью можно использовать метод `AsNoTracking`:

```
currentEmployee = db.Employees.AsNoTracking().Where(...).Single();
```

Далее, можно выключить создание прокси-классов, это лишит `currentEmployee` ссылки на контекст, позволив добавлять его к неограниченному числу контекстов:

```
using (var db = new DBContext()) 
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    currentEmployee = db.Employees.Where(...).Single();
}
```

Наконец, можно запретить EF создавать прокси для конкретного класса сущности, если объявить этот класс как `sealed`:

```
public sealed class Employee
{
    // ...
}
```

---

PS Использовав любое из приведенных решений (кроме второго), вы столкнетесь с ещё одной проблемой: EF не будет знать, что `currentEmployee` уже лежит в базе данных, и попытается добавить эту сущность в базу ещё раз.

Эта проблема решается через метод `Attach`:

```
using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
{
    db.Employees.Attach(currentEmployee);

    var currentAct = new Act
    {
        Employee = currentEmployee
        // ...
    };

    db.Acts.Add(currentAct);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Альтернативная форма - через модификацию Entry State:

```
db.Entry(currentEmployee).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: Крутой развернутый ответ!! Спасибо)

Comment: может как-то пронумеровать варианты?